# Array to CSV file download in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, csv, download, response-headers

I am having an array and i am trying to download it as csv file
my array looks like this

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2017-01-02
        [Name] => Asia consumer MC Alpha bmk - risk
        [Level] => .333000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2017-01-03
        [Name] => Asia consumer MC Alpha bmk - risk
        [Level] => .333000
    ))
```

my code to convert the array to file is

```
public function DownloadFile($filetype,$Array_data,$content){

    $LevelArray = array('Date','Name','Level');

    $selected_array =  $LevelArray;
    if($filetype =='csv'){

            $Filename ='Level.csv';
            header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');                
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
            filename='.$Filename.'');
            // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
            $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($output, $selected_array);
            foreach ($Array_data as $row){
                fputcsv($output, $row);
            }
            fclose($output);                
        }}
```

in response i am getting the output on response but that response is not converted into a file type though headers are pointing to get the csv file from it.

```
 Date,Name,Level
2017-01-02,"Asia consumer MC Alpha bmk - risk",.333000
2017-01-03,"Asia consumer MC Alpha bmk - risk",.333000
2017-01-04,"Asia consumer MC Alpha bmk - risk",.333000
```

I have tried using response method of laravel and many others too nothings seems to work, its headers not able to force browser to download the file

RESPONSE Headers look like this

```
Connection:close
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=Benchmark-Level.csv
Content-type:text/csv;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8000
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.25
```

Comment: How are you returning your response?

Comment: i am just setting headers and putting results to a file which im opening same thing worked in codeigniter but not working here

Answer (score 2):

Is your 2nd header split over 2 lines? It needs to be a single line with no line breaks.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$Filename.'');
```

**Edit**

This code is working for me. I added one more header to force download, but it works in Chrome with or without that extra header. Could you please try running it in different browsers? My thought is that there are browser settings
preventing the download.

```
<?php

$selected_array = array('header:col1','header:col2', 'header:col3');

$Array_data = array(
    array('row1:col1','row1:col2', 'row1:col3'),
    array('row2:col1','row2:col2', 'row2:col3'),
    array('row3:col1','row3:col2', 'row3:col3'),
);

$Filename ='Level.csv';
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
Header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$Filename.'');
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, $selected_array);
foreach ($Array_data as $row){
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
fclose($output);
?>
```

Comment: its in single line only